# Remove all traces of emacs and start over

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, emacs

I've been trying to install [PolyML](http://www.polyml.org) in Emacs on my Mac in OSX but I can't get that or [SML-mode](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/Emacs/sml-mode.html) to work. I've tried the builtin emacs, the gui version and the one from homebrew. Neither poly or sml works in any of them.

How can I start over with just the built-in Emacs with default settings without reinstalling the entire OS? I don't want anything from the other versions left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed Emacs installed through homebrew simply by using the command

`$ brew remove emacs`

The GUI version was removed by simply dragging it to the trash.

I then finally fixed PolyML by once again installing emacs through Homebrew with

`$ brew install emacs —cocoa`

Then in `.bashrc` I added

```
alias emacs=”/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw"
```

This points the emacs command to the correct version. I downloaded PolyML again and it worked great both in the terminal and inside emacs.

Comment: homebrew installation command should be:
`brew install emacs --with-cocoa`